# SCSS / SASS - Dynamic generation of CSS classes

Tags: css, sass

I just came upon a situation where I wanted to automatically generate a series of css classes with help of a mixin. So I was wondering if there is a way to make this dynamically.

Basically I have classes like

```
.tile-1, .tile-2, .tile-3, .tile-4 ...
```

Where tile-2 is double the height of tile-1, tile-3 three times the height of tile-1, and so on

I also created a very simple mixin to be able to set the base-height in a scss variable and calculate it from there:

```
@mixin tile-height($size) {
    height: $size * $tile-height;
}
```

Where `$tile-height` is being loaded from another scss file.

Is there a way to generate my tile-x classes dynamically in the stylesheet, using the number from the classname as a mixin parameter?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Is this what you are looking [`@for`](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#for)?

```
$tile-height: 20;

@mixin tile-height($size) {
  height: $size * $tile-height + px;
}

@for $i from 1 through 5 {
  .tile-#{$i} { @include tile-height($i); }
}
```

Comment: exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot!